# Should I use a try/catch statement with the DataAdapter.Fill method?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, using-statement

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(XYZ.Globals.ConnectionString))
{                                                                                
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter())                            
    {                                                                                
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("selCompanies", sqlConn)      
        {                                                                        
             CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure                            
        };                                                                       
        command.Parameters.AddRange(searchParams.ToArray());                         
        adapter.SelectCommand = command;                                             
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();                                                  
        adapter.Fill(ds);                                                            

        return ds;                                                                   
    }                                                                                
}                                                                                    
                                                                                       Do I need to wrap the `adapter.fill()` in try catch finally block?
```

Comment: Only catch it if you can handle whatever it throws.

Comment: The code snippet above is missing the statements to open and close the db connection. While sanitizing the code, I deleted them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on whether this code is wrapped for exception handling at a higher level.  At what scope do you want to handle errors in this logic - typically this would be for a given 'block' of logic, not for each function call.  Handling DB errors **is** a good idea in general.

In any case, you do need to have another `using` on your `SqlCommand` or you will leak it.

Comment: If I wrap the SqlCommand with a using statement, then there wont be any leaks, when an exception is thrown. Is this right?

Comment: @Full Metal - yes, if this is your full logic.

Comment: Well, in fact, `SqlCommand` doesn't leak (have a look in Reflector). You are right, of course, that *in principle* everything that is `IDisposable` should be `using`'d. (`SqlCeCommand`, for example, *does* leak if not disposed properly...)

Answer (score 1):

You only wrap things in a `try/catch` when you can handle whatever exceptions it throws.  If you can't, there's no need to put it in a `try/catch` block.

The `using` statement is equivalent to a `try/finally` block.

Answer (score 1):

The question would be *what would I do differently if something went wrong*. Typically, the *correct* action is to just let the exception raise upwards - after all, you weren't *expecting* an exception, so you can't do anything useful with it. The only subtlety here is `IDisposable`, where you actively want to clean things up as you go; so `using` statements for things like `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataReader` etc are ideal (But that is `try`/`finally`, not `try`/`catch`). So the main change I would make tour code would be to dispose the command:

```
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("selCompanies", sqlConn))
{
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    //...snip...
}
```

Comment: I want to make sure that if something went wrong, I'd be closing the conenction. Would my code snippet guarntee that?

Comment: +1. I'm dealing with that right now in my application, people aren't disposing of the SQLCommand objects in a deterministic way.

Comment: Thanks Marc, Now I get it. "using" statement generates try and finally so, if I wrap an IDisposable object with using, then it will be disposed off properly. On the other hand, If want to explicitly handle the exception use try catch finally.

Answer (score 0):

The same applies this `adapter.Fill()` as to any other line of .net code:

*If you have a good reason for catching and handling one particular exception, then catch it and handle it. If you don't have a good reason, don't catch it.*

I don't see why this particular line should be error-handled in a specific way.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to catch the exception from the fill here if you have error handling that will require the connection or command to be in scope.

Also, technically the adapter and the command will go out of scope as soon as you exit the using block for the connection. In many cases, this is probably sufficient to release those resources (the connection is the most valuable resource in most scenarios, since it creates overhead on the database server). It doesn't hurt to be explicit, though, especially if you're going to create multiple commands or adapters for the same conntection.